# How to save in specific folder a PDF from print file

Tags: gnome, printing, pdf

I have a strange behaviour while printing to PDF.  I am not very sure when it started to do but I got it on several computers with 12.10 and 13.04 flavors.

When I print to PDF file in a different folder than the default home, by selecting the folder 'Save in folder' of the print dialog box,
whatever which folder I select, the save is always made in my home folder.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?
In the first case if anyone could confirm it here,  I would be more confident for filling a bug report, in second case anybody could point me how to do would be great !

Tks for help

Comment: You can learn how to file a bug report from the [Ubuntu Documentation Reporting Bugs wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: I am using Gnome-3 and now I just try a print to pdf in Gnome classic and there is no problem there, so maybe it is a Gnome-3 specific bug ?

Comment: Same thing happens to me on 13.04. If you filed a bug, would you mind linking to it?

Comment: I have filled a bug report in launchpad : Bug #1218986 - Tks for your support

Answer (score 0):

This problem have been fixed in 13.10.